# How to save multiple .kml files with differnet names in matlab

Tags: save, kml

Below there is a very useful command to convert your file to .kml file so to plot it in google earth.

```
output = ge_plot(data(:,2),data(:,1)); 
 ge_output('name.kml',output);
```

But this works only for one file per time.Lets say i have n files so i want to create n .kml files.
I have changed the first line of the code to this:

```
for i=1:n
   each_traj{i} = out(:,:,i);
   output{i} = ge_plot(each_traj{1,i}(:,2),each_traj{1,i}(:,1));
end
```

And it works. So I have a n dimentional "each_traj" with the information in every cell.
What about the second line?

```
ge_output('traj1.kml',output{1,i})
```

I want to save n traj at the same time, with different names each, of course.
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If any other interested with the same problem here is the sub-code

```
 for i=1:count_cases
   each_traj{i} = out(:,:,i);     
   kml_line(each_traj{1,i}(:,2), each_traj{1,i}(:,1),sprintf('traj%d', i),'w', 6);
end
```

, where each_traj, put your data file